# Handling of USB connection breaks in Python3

Tags: pi-4, usb, serial

I have USB connection from RPI4 to Pico, usually occupying ttyACM1, but occasionally after connection break/boot it may  get values ACM2 or AMA0

I am trying to build an automatic recovery if USB is disconnected or changed after reboot, and tried to built error handling, and successed here in startup

But then if connection break during operation I cannot get over this cycle of exceptions

```
**Runtime error**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 603, in write
    n = os.write(self.fd, d)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/IsmoCodes/USBwrite_to_PicoTeho_v8.2.8_ACM1.py", line 155, in main
    ser.write(kwh_teho_str.encode('utf-8'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 637, in write
    raise SerialException('write failed: {}'.format(e))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: [Errno 5] Input/output error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/IsmoCodes/USBwrite_to_PicoTeho_v8.2.8_ACM1.py", line 294, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/IsmoCodes/USBwrite_to_PicoTeho_v8.2.8_ACM1.py", line 222, in main
    except 'Input/output error':
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

The exception attempt I have nested:

```
except 'Input/output error':
    try:
        print("connection break")
        time.sleep(6)
        continue
    except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
        try:
            print("serial error")

        except 'Input/output error':
            print("nested2 error")
            print("connection2 break")
            time.sleep(6)
            continue
```

OK I managed to get over, rather than caring what specific error there comes, I did a simple single handling for any error. If connection breaks, it tries to toggle between portsm and once connected back it runs smoothly

```
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: " + str(e))
    print("Try to switch port, old was : ",port)
    if port ==  '/dev/ttyACM1':
        port = '/dev/ttyACM2'
    else:
        port = '/dev/ttyACM1'
    print("New port ", port)
    Globaali_paalla = 0
    USB_on = 0
    
    time.sleep(60)
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using serial, you may try to identify your device by e.g. `hwid`, USB Vendor ID (`VID`) or USB Product ID (`PID`) instead of fixed port name. Have a look at the [`serial.tools.list_ports` documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html) to see how you can get the information about your device. Once you know the `VID` and `PID` you can use `serial_for_url()` to initialize your `Serial` object ([see the documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/url_handlers.html)), by e.g.:

```py
vid = 1234  # Put your VID here
pid = 5678  # Put your PID here
port_url = f"hwgrep://{vid}:{pid}"
serial_port = serial.serial_for_url(url=port_url)
```

Pay attention to [`do_not_open` and `boudrate` keyword arguments](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.serial_for_url) to ensure you get expected behavior.